# Generate project files from Publish profile

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've accidentally deleted project files but have got Publish Profile folder. Is there a way to generate project files back from Publish Profile folder? Thanks

Comment: Do you have the source code files? if yes then you have to create a new empty web application and then "add existing files" to it. If no then its better you keep the backup before deleting files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. A publish profile [contains information about publishing a project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398069(v=vs.110).aspx), not what that project looks like.

Next time, use source control and take regular backups of important files.

Comment: I found this: [link](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/291922-convert-dll-cs-file.aspx). Do you think it can help? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: What do you mean by "Publish Profile folder", the deployed project?  And what do you mean by "project files", source code or .csproj? Can you create a recipe from a baked cookie? You can always try decompiling the assemblies and see if the code resembles what you used to compile it.

Comment: See duplicate. See also [How to view source code of dll files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168794/how-to-view-source-code-of-dll-files).